# How can I post via WordPress admin UI with my custom form?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to build an interface with a form, which when submitted, posts to the WordPress database so that if I'm the admin of a WP site, I can just use that one interface to edit my content.

I suppose I could use cURL and post to the WP admin interface but I imagine there's a better way.

Any idea, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress supports the [XML-RPC spec](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/default.html), so I think that would be your best bet for programmatically adding content to your WordPress site.

I'm curious *why* you want to do this, though. It seems more efficient to either use the WP admin interface, or not use WordPress at all. I'm not trying to be snarky, just genuinely curious.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. Good starting point.
Well, some not so tech-savvy clients don't like shifting to a new UI. It would be easier to edit the existing simply interfaces than customize the many options in the WP admin interface.

Do you think that's a bad idea for any reason?

Comment: That makes sense, especially if you're going to have to retrain a bunch of clients on a new system when the old one is easy and familiar to them. I got the impression from your original post that it was you that didn't want to learn the new interface, but I see I was wrong. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Thanks again, Chris :)

Also, if it helps anyone, I find these useful:
 * [XML-RPC wp](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp)
 * [XML-RPC Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support)
 * [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/)